# calcular cociente en lenguaje c

Tags: c, matrices

el problema se basa en un porgrama que pide calcular la suma de los elementos por encima de la diagonal secundaria, calcular la suma de la diagonal secundaria y dividir lo primero por lo segundo (matrices), es decir : suma elementos por encima de diagonal secundaria / suma diagonal secundaria.
el cociente debe ser obligatoriamente enviado desde el main y el calculo del cociente y lo demas dentro de una funcion.
aqui les dejo el codigo:

```
int main( void ) {
  int     mat2A[TAM_MAT][TAM_MAT];
  float   cociente;

  puts("Probando parte 2-a.-");
  cargarMatParteA(mat2A, TAM_MAT, TAM_MAT, !CON_CERO, NEGA1);
  mostrarMatParteA(mat2A, TAM_MAT, TAM_MAT);

  if(calcularcociente_mia(mat2A, TAM_MAT, TAM_MAT, &cociente))
    printf("El cociente es %f.\n\n", cociente);
}   

int calcularcociente_mia(int mat[][TAM_MAT], int cantFi, int cantCo, float *cociente) {
  int suma=0;
  int  sumadiagonal=0;

  for (cantFi=TAM_MAT-1;cantFi>=0;cantFi--) {
    for(cantCo=0;cantCo<TAM_MAT-cantFi-1;cantCo++) {
      suma+= *(mat+cantFi*TAM_MAT+cantCo);
    }
  }

  for(cantFi=0,cantCo=TAM_MAT-1;cantFi<TAM_MAT;cantFi++,cantCo--) {
    sumadiagonal+= *(mat+cantFi*TAM_MAT+cantCo);
  }

  *cociente =  (float) suma/(float)sumadiagonal;

  return cociente;
}
```

Comment: error no da. lo que pasa es que no me da el cociente precisamente es decir. si el cociente es 0,50 o mayor lo aproxima a 1

Comment: En el titular de la pregunta hablas de [tag:c] y sin embargo la pregunta está etiquetada como [tag:c++] ¿Qué opción es la correcta?

Comment: Por otro lado... tu ejemplo no enseña nada. ¿rellenamos la matriz nosotros a mano? ¿Qué tal si proporcionas un ejemplo completo compilable y ejecutable que reproduzca el problema? Por ejemplo la función `calcularcociente_mia` devuelve un valor via `return` que no estás usando... ¿eso es significativo? tu pregunta no es todo lo precisa que debiera.

Comment: rellenar la matriz a mano o random no afecta en nada. para eso no pido ayuda segun tu logica y  listo. tu pregunta no aporta en nada. stackoverflow es para  ayudar

Comment: A ver si soy capaz de explicarlo de forma sencilla. SO no es un portal para responderte a ti única y exclusivamente. Tu obligación al preguntar es exponer preguntas claras, concisas y completas y tu obligación al responder será presentar respuestas claras, concisas y completas. De nada sirve tener un catálogo inmenso de preguntas y respuestas si las mismas están incompletas y con carencias graves.

Comment: Por otro lado piensa que quien te responde te está ofreciendo gratuitamente unos servicios por los que en otros casos (como en su trabajo) cobra por ellos así que solo por ese detalle tonto deberías intentar facilitar toda la información posible. Cuando decimos que es necesario presentar un ejemplo mínimo y **completo** es por varias razones como por ejemplo poder evaluar **todo** el código involucrado en el error y que al elaborar dicho ejemplo puede suceder que tu mismo encuentres el error y de esa experiencia aprenderás mucho más que si te damos la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que la función `calcularcociente_mia` está mal definida ya que está como `int` cuando debería devolver un `float`.

Además estaba mal la forma de acceder a los elementos de la matriz dentro de la función. Dado que las matrices son vectores de vectores el hacer `*(mat+1)` lleva al segundo vector fila y el hacer `**(mat+1)` llevaría al primer elemento de la segunda fila.
A continuación una versión corregida modificada para pruebas.

```
#define TAM_MAT 2 //Para probar
float calcularcociente_mia(int mat[][TAM_MAT], int cantFi, int cantCo, float *cociente) {
  int suma=0;
  int sumadiagonal=0;

  for (cantFi=TAM_MAT-1;cantFi>=0;cantFi--) {
    for(cantCo=0;cantCo<TAM_MAT-cantFi-1;cantCo++) {
      suma+= mat[cantFi][cantCo];
    }
  }

  for(cantFi=0,cantCo=TAM_MAT-1;cantFi<TAM_MAT;cantFi++,cantCo--) {
    sumadiagonal+= mat[cantFi][cantCo];
  }

  *cociente =  (float) suma/(float)sumadiagonal;

  return *cociente;
}

int main ()
  {
  int     mat2A[TAM_MAT][TAM_MAT] = {{2,1},{3,2}}; //Inicializo para probar
  float   cociente;

  puts("Probando parte 2-a.-");
  //cargarMatParteA(mat2A, TAM_MAT, TAM_MAT, !CON_CERO, NEGA1);
  //mostrarMatParteA(mat2A, TAM_MAT, TAM_MAT);


  if(calcularcociente_mia(mat2A, TAM_MAT, TAM_MAT, &cociente))
    printf("El cociente es %f.\n\n", cociente);

  return 0;
}
```